# Creating Community post using Youtube data API

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I wanted to automate the task of posting of community posts on my channel. While going through Youtube Data (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs), I couldn't find any such request.

Could you please guide me if this request is available in youtube API? Also If not, how feasible it would be to accomplish this task using web automation i.e. selenium etc. framework.

Comment: what about this? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Comment: [@CornelRaiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3741900/cornel-raiu) this YouTube Data API v3 endpoint documentation doesn't help to answer the question. The most complicated things are: 1. to stay logged in with your YouTube account with a tool such as Selenium 2. publishing various kinds of posts (polls, texts, images...) may makes things a bit harder. Note that AFAIK the YouTube official API doesn't provide this feature.